# cHow desactivate sound in my App with 1 button?

Tags: audio, unity-game-engine

I have some mp3 audios in some scenes, and I have 1 button in my main scene and I want when user press these button, my App had no mp3 sounds. Do I Have to duplicate my App without sounds? or how?

I have this but not works?

```
public class AudioApp : MonoBehaviour {

    public void SonidoApp() {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("MP3AudioState", 1);

    }

    public void SonidoAppmute() {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("MP3AudioState", 0);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is when the user press the button you save a value in PlayerPrefs (0 for unmuted 1 for muted as an exemple):

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("MP3AudioState", 1);
```

And wherever you play the audio sound all you need to check is the value you saved:

```
if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("MP3AudioState") == 0){ //Play the sound}
```

So if the value you saved was 0 at the time the sound wants to be played you let it pass if it's 1 you don't.

Comment: Do you have an example ? Because If I put ``if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("MP3AudioState") == 0){ _???_ }`` how can I indicate activate all mp3 sounds in my app? I don't understand how

Comment: Can I reference all ``AudioSources`` ? like: ``Colision.sonidoping = false`` or something...

Comment: I have in other Script(**Colision.cs**) my 2 ``audiosources`` _sonidoping_ and _sonidoping2_ -> ``public AudioSource sonidoping;`` and ``public AudioSource sonidoping2`` ,

Comment: @RfMvs You know where you do AudioSource.Play just first check if It is equal to 0.

Answer (score 1):

To disable **all** Audios in your scene, simply change the volume of the current `AudioListener` to zero.

The AudioListener is attached to your camera by default, so this could work for you:

```
Camera.main.GetComponent<AudioListener>.volume = 0;
```